# zsh PROMPT coloring doesn't work inside of tmux

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux, prompt

I have the following line in my `.zshrc`:

```
export PROMPT="%n@%K{9}%m%k:%~# "
```

It works if I connect directly

[image]

But doesn't work inside `tmux`

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: Is your `tmux` configured to start zsh as a login shell, or as a non-login shell? That affects whether it sources .zshrc or .zprofile I think?

Comment: `TERM=tmux tput colors` indicates that that terminal emulator only supports 8 colours on my system. I have `tmux-256color` terminfo entry so maybe tmux can be configured to support 256 colours (assuming its host terminal(s) can too) and  then you'd need to make sure `$TERM` is set to that value if `tmux` doesn't do it already.

Comment: How to do this, don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Addition of

```
set-option -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

to `~/.tmux.conf` helped.